# How can I make a non-breaking space in reStructuredText?

Tags: restructuredtext

How can I make a non-breaking space in reStructuredText?

An obvious but problematic solution is:

```
`word A`
```

But it might be treated differently by different implementations, such as rst2latex or rst2pdf.  Plus it is rendered in italics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see the problem here, running docutils v0.9.
At least rst2latex and rst2html are behaving properly regarding non-breaking whitespace.
Latex generates ~ and html generates &nbsp; when you input a non-breaking character (\xa0, \0240).

Maybe you have an editor issue ? If you can manage to input the character, docutils will do the job.

Comment: a non-visible character is not useful

Comment: Then you can either configure your editor to make it visible or use an extra preprocessing pass in your input files...

Comment: Usually, you are not the only person to edit that file, and other persons may use different editors, and even the persons using the same editor will, most likely, use different configurations...

Answer (score 42):

You need the unicode directive, but it can only be used in substitutions. So you need to define a substitution like this:

```
.. |nbsp| unicode:: 0xA0 
   :trim:
```

and then use it like this:

```
xx |nbsp| xx
```

`:trim:` is there to get rid of those spaces around the substitution.

Comment: It seems that the 0xA0 substitution comes out as character 32 in HTML for me :(

Comment: 1) the xx\ |nbsp|\ xx thing works in the renderer (http://www.tele3.cz/jbar/rest/rest.html)... No idea about 32 :(

Comment: Acc to the documentation, you can pass to the unicode directive the following formats: [decimal numbers or hexadecimal numbers, prefixed by 0x, x, \x, U+, u, or \u or as XML-style hexadecimal character entities, e.g. &#x1a2b;]. Maybe you can experiment with different notation for nbsp which acc to Wikipedia are [U+00A0   no-break space (HTML: &#160; &nbsp;). Can be encoded by UTF-8 as 0xC2 0xA0.]

Comment: I tried again and this does seem to be working. You can add ``:trim:`` to the directive to get it to ignore the spaces around the substitution. If you update the answer with the trim, the bounty is yours - thanks!

Comment: pleasure doing business with you :)

Comment: `|nbsp|` is defined in https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docutils/parsers/rst/include/isonum.txt (though without the trim)

Comment: @jterrace The NBSP is written to the *.html file but drag-and-drop from the HTML browser (firefox) returned an ordinary space here.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `|_|` in place of `|nbsp|` which is less visually intrusive, given reStructuredText's goal of being readable as plain text.

Comment: @Davide and end up being hidden by 'show n more comments' label

Answer (score 2):

I ended up coming up with a workaround for Sphinx. I overwrite the HTML and LaTeX writers to convert the `~` character to a non-breaking space. Here's the HTML one:

```py
import sphinx.writers.html
BaseTranslator = sphinx.writers.html.SmartyPantsHTMLTranslator

class CustomHTMLTranslator(BaseTranslator):
    
    def bulk_text_processor(self, text):
        if '~' in text:
            text = text.replace('~', '&nbsp;')
        return text

sphinx.writers.html.SmartyPantsHTMLTranslator = CustomHTMLTranslator
```

and the LaTeX one:

```py
import sphinx.writers.latex
BaseTranslator = sphinx.writers.latex.LaTeXTranslator

class DocTranslator(BaseTranslator):

    def visit_Text(self, node):
        if self.verbatim is not None:
            self.verbatim += node.astext()
        else:
            text = self.encode(node.astext())
            if '\\textasciitilde{}' in text:
                text = text.replace('\\textasciitilde{}', '~')
            if not self.no_contractions:
                text = educate_quotes_latex(text)
            self.body.append(text)

sphinx.writers.latex.LaTeXTranslator = DocTranslator
```

It's not so pretty, and it doesn't even let you escape the `~` character, but it works for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it but maybe you can use http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#unicode-character-codes and the unicode "no break space" character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

A third alternative besides a literal NBSP and a custom "unicode" substitution is
including a [reStructuredText Standard Definition File](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/definitions.html), e.g.

```
.. include:: <isonum.txt>

xx\ |nbsp|\ xx
```

The escaped spaces are required, because the standard definition file does not use the `:trim:` option.