# Non breaking spaces in RstDocument in Kivy

Tags: python, restructuredtext, kivy

Is there any chance to perform non breaking spaces in RstDocument?

I need move one letter words to next line if this word is on the end of line.

I tried define Substitution:

```
.. |nbsp| unicode:: 0xA0
   :trim:
```

and then use it in text:

```
some text some text |nbsp| some text some text
```

but Kivy RstDocument render it as:

```
some text some text |nbsp| some text some text
```

Has anybody any suggestion?

Comment: This does seem to be a bug in Kivy. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11830242/623518, which suggests that non-breaking spaces work fine in Docutils (the reference implementation for reStructuredText).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a bug in Kivy.  The above worked fine with the [reST renderer](http://www.tele3.cz/jbar/rest/rest.html) I tried.