# How to force non-breaking space in reStructuredText, in code environment?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have this snippet in my reStructuredText document:

```
  1. Find the file at ``~/Google Drive/code/mac/install.sh``.
```

Notice the code/quote environment.  Notice the space between `Google` and `Drive` in the path.

When rendered with Sphinx in HTML, there is a line-wrap between `Google` and `Drive`, and the space is gone.  (Since this is documentation, I need everything in the code environment to appear to the user exactly as it is entered, which includes the space between 'Google' and 'Drive'.  Not only should a space be present, but it should be shaded grey just like all the other code in the code environment)

How do I tell reStructuredText to use a non-breaking space in that location?

Comment: What about this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12145490/5480526

Comment: No, this does not work.  The solution must work in a reST quote environment (see the double backticks), so there is a need to escape quote mode in order to input something special.

Comment: I get two `<span>` elements separated by a space in the output: `<span class="pre">~/Google</span>` and `<span class="pre">Drive/Quisquam/code/repo/latest/application-bundles/mac/install.sh</span>`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @mzjn Yes, and a regular old space between the two.  Either `<span class="pre">~/Google Drive/Quisquam/code/repo/latest/application-bund‌​les/mac/install.sh</‌​span>` or at worst case `<span class="pre">~/Google</span><span class="pre"> Drive/Quisquam/code/repo/latest/application-bund‌​les/mac/install.sh</‌​span>` would be preferable to the current behavior.

Comment: Oh man, Stack Overflow has the same bad behavior!

Comment: In the question you say that there is a line-wrap in the output. What does that mean exactly? Because now you say that it is a "regular old space". And why is this a problem in the first place?

Comment: @mzjn The HTML *source code* has a regular old space between `<span class="pre">~/Google</span>` and `<span class="pre"> Drive/Quisquam/code/repo/latest/application-bund‌​les/mac/in‌​stall.sh</‌​span>`.  The HTML when *rendered* in a browser has a line-wrap between "Google" and "Drive".

Comment: @mzjn This is a problem because the quote environment is meant to quote content exactly.  But the content does not to appear to the user as it is (the space is missing).  This is bad in documentation, since the user is required to type quoted things verbatim into certain prompts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me if the regular space character is replaced with a non-breaking space (U+00A0) in the reST file. That will produce a single `<span>` element containing `Google&nbsp;Drive` in the output:

```
<span class="pre">~/Google&nbsp;Drive/code/mac/install.sh</span>
```

Inserting a literal non-breaking space can be done in several ways. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Keyboard_entry_methods.

Comment: this looks like the better solution because it still allows wrapping in browser at slashes. And copy paste from browser window will get a normal space. At least in my brief testing...

Comment: I was able to enter the character in Emacs using `Ctrl-x 8 <space>`. It can also be copied from the Character Map program on Windows.

Comment: on some keyboards, <alt><space> or <altgr><space> (not tested on Windows)

Comment: This is a good solution because it will work not only for HTML output, but also for any supported output types.

Comment: I'm not happy with this solution, because it will cause hard-to-debug errors if someone tries to copy-paste and use the code with a non-breaking space in it.

Answer (score 2):

Put some css in a file  `_static/custom.css` at top repertory in your project

```
code.docutils.literal {
    white-space : pre;
}
```

(I don't know how from CSS allow breaks say at slashes but not at spaces).

<strike>For the `&nbsp;` approach you can do this:</strike>

```
1. Find the file in our Google Drive folder It is located at
   ``~/Google`` |_| ``Drive/Quisquam/code/repo/latest/application-bundles/mac/install.sh``.

.. |_| unicode:: 0x00A0
       :trim:
```

Edit: much better than second approach is as pointed in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325894/how-do-i-force-a-space-to-be-preserved-in-restructuredtext/42635643?noredirect=1#comment72409775_37325894) to use a NO-BREAK SPACE in the reST source. Then the HTML will use `&nbsp;`, and the URL will still wrap at slashes contrarily to first approach above which makes it really unwrapping (in my brief investigation).

I had used second approach in other context (also targeting LaTeX output) to insert Unicode+202F, and it had slipped out my mind that for Unicode+00A0, one only has to use it directly in reST source.

Comment: Is the space shaded grey like the rest of the text?  Is it apparent to the user that a space is between "Google" and "Drive"?

Comment: didn't you try? in the first approach the space is like rest of the text, in the second the shading is interrupted. At least with alabaster theme which is default in current Sphinx. But this is because shading comes from some css for pre, if you transfer it to code.docutils.literal there will be no interruption of shading also in second approach (which I included only to answer your query about inserting a ``&nbsp;`` entity; the first approach seems the better way).

Comment: The CSS modification `white-space: pre;` is okay, but simply using a block quote is a better solution, since it will work on more than HTML outputs.  The NO-BREAK SPACE approach sounds fantastic!  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working.  I am using Sphinx with Python3.5.  I use the `sphinx-build` command to kick things off.  The sphinx-build file has the flag, `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`.  I am manually copying and pasting a NO-BREAK SPACE character from a browser into the document.  I have tried multiple websites and multiple text editors, to no avail.

Comment: I get same result as in [mzjn answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42655779/4184837). But notice that when copying from the browser window I get a normal space from the `&nbsp;` entity in html source. There are may ways depending on platform and software to insert Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to add the following css to the `custom.css` and make `background-color` match the pre `background-color`

```
tt, 
code {
    color: #839496;
    background-color: #073642;
}
```