# Avoiding line breaks in sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

How can I keep two words on the same line when generating sphinx documentation? For example, I want no line breaks between `2` and `sec` in `2 sec`. For example, I want to avoid  the following layout:

```
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text and then done in 2
sec
```

and to get the following instead:

```
some text some text some text some text some text some text some text and then done in
2 sec
```

In LaTex in this case one can achieve this with `~`: `2~sec`.

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have tried and what output format you want (HTML, PDF, etc.).

Comment: Try using a non-breaking space. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42655779/407651

Comment: @StevePiercy that should hopefully be independent of the output format. If sphinx-doc does not support this, that would be bad.

Answer (score 1):

Best way I found regardless of output format (?) is using **substitutions** and **Unicode**.

Edit your conf.py to introduce global substitutions:

```
rst_epilog = """
.. |nbh| unicode:: U+2011
   :trim:
.. |nbsp| unicode:: U+00A0
   :trim:
"""
```

Then use in RST as substition (note I need to write `|nbsp|` with surrounding blanks, otherwise the substition would not get picked up.
Worked for me with HTML **and** PDF.

References:

Epilog:
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_epilog

Substitutions:
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#substitutions

Unicode directive:
https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#unicode-character-codes

Unicode Characters:
Non-Breaking Hyphen: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2011

Non-Breaking Space: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00A0